# how to add special charecters in string concatenation

Tags: string, concatenation, system-verilog

I want to get the following into single string variable:

```
cfg_hier = save("uvm_test_top.uvc_tb.env.dram(M)","registers.nw");
```

I want to get "uvm_test_top.uvc_tb.env.dram(M)","registers.nw" into string called `soc_hier` so that I can pass as follows:

```
cfg_hier = save(soc_hier);
```

Comment: What is `save()` supposed to mean? String concatenation uses {}'s

Comment: soc_hier = "uvm_test_top.uvc_tb.env.dram(M)","registers.nw"

Comment: soc_hier should be as above mentioned  including " . save is internal function which take hierarcy.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation

```
soc_hier = save({"uvm_test_top.uvc_tb.env.dram(M)","registers.nw"});
```